# Changing order of integration on stochastic term in Vasicek

Tags: stochastic-calculus, vasicek

This  question is in relation to the vasicek model, where i am trying to find the solution.

I have this term: $-\int_{t}^{T} \sigma \int_{t}^{s} e^{-\kappa(s-u)} d W(u) d s$

I need to change the integrals like this: $-\sigma \int_{t}^{T} \int_{u}^{T} e^{-\kappa(s-u)} d s d W(u)$

but i have absolutely no idea how he goes from $\int_{t}^{s}$ to $\int_{u}^{T}$.

I know about the changing order of integration, but this is (from what i understand) not what has been done. The rest of the integration should be straight forward, once i understand how i do this.

Comment: The double integral is on $(u, s) \in [t, T]^2$ with $u<s$, so:
$$\int_t^T \int_t^s f(u,s) dW(u) ds = \int_t^T \int_t^T 1_{u<s} f(u,s) dW(u) ds = \int_t^T \int_t^T 1_{u<s} f(u,s) ds dW(u) = \int_u^T \int_t^T f(u,s) ds dW(u) $$
Of course, the function $f$ has to satisfy some conditions so that all the terms above have a meaning, in particular $\int_u^T (\int_t^T f(u,s) ds)^2 du < \infty$ which is the case here.

Comment: Hi: Someone else hopefully can explain it in more detail but the idea  is that $u$ has to be less than $s$  ( e has to be raised to a negative power ) in order to have mean reversion. But in the original integral, $s$ goes from $t$ to $T$  so the bottom limit in the outside integral has to be changed to be from $t$ to $u$ for that condition to hold. Also,  dW(u) ( which can be thought of as W(du) ) goes from $t$ to $s$ in the original integral,  so the upper limit in the inside integral needs to be changed from $s$ to $T$. Then,  you can flip the order of the integrals.

Comment: @mbih: byouness explained it in a much clearer way than I did  but the idea is the same.

Comment: @markleeds what is this called? Im not getting what you guys are exlaining to me, even though it sounds totally correct. There must be some way i can read about this concept, but i dont know the name / method.

Comment: It's a form of Fubini's theorem that permits to change the order of integrals in a double integral.

Comment: @mbih:  I don't think there's a name for it.  We have a double integral where both of the lower limits start at $t$ The $du$ integral ends at time $T$ and the $dw$ integral  ends at time $s$. But $u$ and $s$ have to satisfy a condition that $u$ is less than $s$. which means that the  the limits of their respective integrals are not free to just be what they were originally. The integral limits need to be changed sso that the condition that $u$ is less than $s$ is always satisfied. By changing the bottom limit on the $ds$ integral to $u$ it is guaranteed that $s$ > $u$.

Comment: Finally,  the upper limit of the $du$ integral can be changed to $T$ because $du$ can traverse the whole [t,T] range as long as the $u < s$ condition is satisfied. I hope this helps but maybe byouness can explain it more clearly. If you try to calculate the area of a triangle in 2 dimensions ( with x and y axis ) using a double integral, you will see that the same concept arise there so maybe make up some triangle and try to integrate to obtain its area.